# Is there a way to configure port security on Linux bridge?

Tags: linux, security, linux-networking, bridge, ethernet

On switches there is such a feature as [Port Security](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4000/8-2glx/configuration/guide/sec_port.html). Roughly speaking it allows to control, which exactly MAC's can be on the specific switch port. You can restrict it to just one MAC or several, and Ethernet frames from some new device will be blocked.

So is there a way to do it in Linux bridge?

[This post](https://www.keypressure.com/blog/linux-bridge-port-security/) didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`mac`](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/iptables/iptables-extensions.8.en.html#mac) iptables match extension.

> it allows to control, which exactly MAC's can be on the specific switch port. You can restrict it to just one MAC or several, and Ethernet frames from some new device will be blocked.

to simulate that, assuming your bridge interface is `br0`, and MAC addresses you want to allow are `00:01:02:03:04:05` and `01:02:03:04:05:06`, you may probably use this:

```sh
iptables -A INPUT -i br0 -m mac --mac-source 00:01:02:03:04:05 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i br0 -m mac --mac-source 01:02:03:04:05:06 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i br0 -j DROP
```